# Is it possible to get a user's entire Google Play Achievement history?

Tags: google-play, achievements

For an app I'm developing, I'd like to retrieve all of a user's Google Play Achievements. Looking through the Play Game Services API, I'm not sure if this is possible. It seems like you can only get Achievements for a user for a specific game, and I don't see any way to get all of the games a user has played, either.

Has anyone been able to do this, or something like this? I expect the answer is 'no, that's not at all possible', but I'm hoping there's something I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Privacy considerations mean the user id is different between games, and this information is not shared.